# I can't make two ec2 instance talk each other

Tags: amazon-web-services, api, networking, amazon-ec2, architecture

My goal:

I have two instance EC2, one is an API that is public and another is a microservice, which needs only to communicate with API.

what I have tried so far:

I have one security group where both instances were attached. In this group, I created every possible rules. (I can ping each of them through private IP, but i can't make a request from my API to my microservice).

I made a simple diagram showing my goal and my problem

[image]

More details:

- Both instance are running on the same VPC and subnet.
- Trying telnet or curl, the response is connection refused

My inbound rules security group:

[image]

My outbound rules security group:

[image]

Comment: You can't connect to both instances, or only to the private microservice? And what do you understand by "private microservices" and "public API", if both are in the same subnet?

Comment: Hi, Marcin!

I have an API, that works normally, I can make requests from the internet, it's all good. But this public API needs to make requests to another API, that's in the same VPC, this 'microservice' is only to respond the main API (public API as in the picture), but the main API can't communicate with it. It's a simple scenario where two servers need to communicate privately. 

Thanks, dude!

Comment: Are you sure that the pubic API is NOT using the internet to access the private API? For example, the private API call is not performed in a web-browser using javascript.

Comment: Now I'm not sure...
But, in Public API, I make requests passing private ip and port...
I tried telnet, connection refused

Comment: I can ping between instances by private ip

Comment: Did you setup any instance level firewall? Does your private API even wroks? Can you `curl localhost:8086` when you ssh to the private instance?

Comment: I don't make any specific config level network. All default. 

Inside private API by ssh, I can make curl localhost, my application respond normally

Comment: In that case I would go the the begginig, and start from scratch. The issue must be some very small mistake somewhere. Re-doing it could inidacte what is the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Security Group rules operate on each resource *individually*. Putting instances in the 'same' security group does not guarantee that they can communicate with each other.

The correct security setup would be:

- One Security Group on the 'public' instance (`Public-SG`) that allows **Inbound** connections on port 80/443 from the Internet (`0.0.0.0/0`) and default rules that **permit All Outbound traffic**.
- One Security Group on the 'private' microservice instance (`Microservice-SG`) that allows **Inbound** connections on port 8086 from `Public-SG` and default rules that **permit All Outbound traffic**.

That is, `Microservice-SG` should specifically reference `Public-SG` in its Inbound rules.

Comment: Hi John! 

I tried what you recommend. I created two SG, attached each service on each one of them, I created a rule from Public-SG and still no connection ... 

More details: I disabled firewall from both linux 

Another idea?

Thank you!

Comment: You can test it by temporarily opening the Security Group on `Microservice-SG` to `0.0.0.0/0` for All Traffic. If it still doesn't work, then the fault lies somewhere else (not with the Security Group). Make sure that `Public-SG` allows ALL Outbound traffic and also make sure you haven't changed any of the Network ACLs from their standard "Allow All" settings.

Comment: I opened all traffic to 0.0.0.0/0 on microservice-sg, and still doesn't work.

- ACL is all standard, allow All Traffic

I'm starting to believe that problem is in the applications, but it does not make sense to me. I can run both application locally and make then communicate.

I'm frustrate :((